# Are NSColors like tungsten and steel also available?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, properties, nscolor

I know Cocoa gives you `whiteColor`, `blackColor`, `darkGrayColor`, but do they also have the colors from in Apple's color panel? With colors like "Snow", "Tungsten", "Steel", "Tin" ? Or should I create those myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [NSColorList](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorList_Class/). [The one named](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorList_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColorList/colorListNamed:) “Crayons” corresponds to the crayon box in the Color Panel.

Comment: +1 It goes to show that even after years of using Cocoa, I still discover new classes all the time.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Didn't know that class existed.

Answer (score 1):

You should find the rgb values for those colors and make your own NSColor. Documentation for NSColor from rgb [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/clm/NSColor/colorWithCalibratedRed%3Agreen%3Ablue%3Aalpha%3A)

Comment: That's what I thought too but in the comment above, Peter proofed us wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ***`Categories`*** to `NSColor` and make ANY color with ANY name you want… So you need a make 2 files… `NSColor+YourCategories.h`…

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface NSColor (YourCategories)  // Tag in () is "yours" to name,
+ (NSColor *) MAUVE;
@end
```

and an aptly named `NSColor+YourCategories.m` file

```
#import "NSColor+YourCategories.h"
@implementation NSColor (YourCategories)
+ (NSColor *) MAUVE { static NSColor*  MAUVE = nil;  if( MAUVE == nil )
              MAUVE = [NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.712 green:0.570 blue:0.570 alpha:1.000];r
       return MAUVE;
 }
```

The simply

`#import NSColor+YourCategories.h`

on any page which you want to be able to refer to your named colors, like…

```
[[self window]setBackGroundColor: [NSColor MAUVE]];
```

∀Ⓛ∃✖